# calling a function from a function in pageobjects - protractor

Tags: function, protractor

I have a function that i am trying to call from another function within the pageobjects file.

```
    this.clickbutton = function(method){
    if(method == 'phone'){
        phonebutton.click();
        comment.sendKeys('comments');
        submitbutton.click();
    }else if(method == 'email'){
        emailbutton.click();
    }else if(method == 'sms'){
        smsbutton.click();
    }else{
        rowphonebutton.click();
        comment.sendKeys('comments');
        submitbutton.click();
    }
};
```

My another function within the same PO file.

```
    this.contactagentAll = function(method){
    getrow.count().then(function(cnt){
        if(cnt>0){
            this.clickbutton(method);
            getrow.count().then(function(cnt1){
               expect(cnt1).toEqual(0); 
            });
        }else{
            console.log('no records found');  
        }
    });
};
```

I get the error saying - Failed: this.clickbutton is not a function. 
any suggestions pls?

Comment: This is a common question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/398606

Comment: how can this be duplicate. the existing one  question pointed to is not at all related to protractor.

Comment: It's a duplicate b/c the problem actually has nothing to do with Protractor, and is just a common problem that people encounter with javascript. If you're stuck, use the `var self = this;` trick in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: @SunilD. thank you :)